# c++ * vs & in function declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

When should I declare my variables as pointers vs objects passed-by-reference? They compile to the same thing in assembly (at least run-time asymptotically) so when should I use which?

```
void foo(obj* param)
void foo(obj& param)
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c among many, many others

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My rule is simple: use * when you want to show that value is optional and thus can be 0.

Excluding from the rule: all the _obj_s around are stored in containers and you don't want to make your code look ugly by using everywhere `foo(*value);` instead of `foo(value);`
So then to show that value can't be 0 put `assert(value);` at the function begin.

Answer (score 6):

I follow the [Google style guide standard](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments) as it makes the most sense to me. It states:

> Within function parameter lists all
>   references must be const:
>
> ```
> void Foo(const string &in, string *out);
> ```
>
> In fact it is a very strong convention
>   in Google code that input arguments
>   are values or const references while
>   output arguments are pointers. Input
>   parameters may be const pointers, but
>   we never allow non-const reference
>   parameters.
>
> One case when you might want an input
>   parameter to be a const pointer is if
>   you want to emphasize that the
>   argument is not copied, so it must
>   exist for the lifetime of the object;
>   it is usually best to document this in
>   comments as well. STL adapters such as
>   bind2nd and mem_fun do not permit
>   reference parameters, so you must
>   declare functions with pointer
>   parameters in these cases, too.

Comment: I do not agree with this point. This is misuse of reference/pointer concept in the language. References are their to ensure at compile-time that a value is initialized. This is a very strong contract where one states the function accepts only initialized values. Languages like Java or C# have lack, which forces developers additionaly to check if the value being passed is NULL (null) or not. I don' see enforcement in the contract that I am allowed to accept only const values.

Answer (score 3):

One reason to use pointers is if it makes sense to pass a `NULL` value into the function. With a pointer, it's expected to be able to do this. With a reference, it is not expected to be able to do this.

(However, by doing tricky things it is still possible to pass a NULL into a reference parameter. You can expect that the called function may crash in this case.)

Another convention is that if you pass a pointer into a function, the function may use the pointer to take ownership of the object (especially in a COM-like reference counted environment). If you pass a reference, then the called function can expect to use the object for the duration of the function call but not to keep a pointer to the object for use later.

Answer (score 2):

The other difference between pointers and references is that it is implied that you won't hold on to a reference, unless you pass one to a constructor.  Passing pointers may mean that an object might hold onto it for a while, like a composite pattern object.

Answer (score 0):

A good reason why I use pointers and not references in my C++ applications, is readability. When using a pointer you see what is really happening, and when using pointers the syntax tells you what's really happening.

Same goes for "0" or "NULL". I prefer using "NULL", this way 3 months later when I see a code that looks like:

```
somevar_1 = 0;
somevar_2 = NULL;
```

I know that `somevar_1` is an `int` (or `float`) and `somevar_2` is some kind of pointer.

Comment: `nullptr` is even better! :P Unfortunately, that requires C++11 support :(