# Confusion about references and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)
>   [What are the distinctions between the various symbols (*,&, etc) combined with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636903/what-are-the-distinctions-between-the-various-symbols-etc-combined-with-p)

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around this example code pasted below. Specifically, the function `Buf& operator=( const Buf & );`. From what I understand, this function expects an address of the object of class `Buf` to be returned. Two questions arise:

1. Is it equally applicable to declare this as `Buf* operator=( const Buf* );`, since `Buf*` is also an address of an instance of class `Buf`? If not, why not? If so, is it just a preference of coding sytle? Which is preferable?
2. In the corresponding function definition, `*this` is returned. From what I understand, `this` is a pointer, or address corresponding to the object of class `Buf`. So `*this` is what the pointer points to, i.e. an object of class `Buf`. Is this in conflict with returning `Buf*`? Should the function return `this` instead of `*this` ?

I guess I'm having one of those days today... please somebody help!!

> ```
> using namespace std;
>
> class Buf  { public:
>     Buf( char* szBuffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer );
>     Buf& operator=( const Buf & );
>     void Display() { cout << buffer << endl; }
>
> private:
>     char*   buffer;
>     size_t  sizeOfBuffer; };
>
> Buf::Buf( char* szBuffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer ) {
>     sizeOfBuffer++; // account for a NULL terminator
>
>     buffer = new char[ sizeOfBuffer ];
>     if (buffer)
>     {
>         strcpy_s( buffer, sizeOfBuffer, szBuffer );
>         sizeOfBuffer = sizeOfBuffer;
>     } }
>
> Buf& Buf::operator=( const Buf &otherbuf )  {
>     if( &otherbuf != this ) 
>     {
>         if (buffer)
>             delete [] buffer;
>
>         sizeOfBuffer =  strlen( otherbuf.buffer ) + 1; 
>         buffer = new char[sizeOfBuffer];
>         strcpy_s( buffer, sizeOfBuffer, otherbuf.buffer );
>     }
>     return *this; }
>
> int main() {
>     Buf myBuf( "my buffer", 10 );
>     Buf yourBuf( "your buffer", 12 );
>
>     // Display 'my buffer'
>     myBuf.Display();
>
>     // assignment opperator
>     myBuf = yourBuf;
>
>     // Display 'your buffer'
>     myBuf.Display(); }
> ```

Comment: Here's the answer you need on `*` vs. `&`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637342/365496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Buf& operator=( const Buf & );
```

returns a reference to a `Buf` object, not an address of a `Buf` object. So when the method returns `*this`, the caller gets a reference to the object.

This:
    Buf* operator=( const Buf * );

returns a pointer to a `Buf`, so the corresponding function would indeed return `this`.

Note that here:

```
Buf& b = <some code returning Buf&>;
```

`b` is a reference to `Buf`, not an address. On the other hand,

```
Buf c = ...
Buf* pBuf = &c;
```

`&c` in the code above *is* the address of `c` and can be used to initialize `pBuf`, which is a pointer to `Buf`. So the `*` and `&` can have different meanings depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand, this function expects an address of the object
>   of class Buf to be returned.

No.

A reference to a Buf object is returned, not an address. A reference is not an address. It is an alias - something used to refer to that precise object. A reference is different from a pointer.

I suggest that you google for C++ references and pointers, or even better, that you read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which explains this concept.

Comment: thanks. i did google it but i agree that a good book is really what i need. off to the library!

Answer (score 3):

`Buf&` is not an "address", it's a reference. Syntactically, you simply return an object, and the caller gets access to the original. In the above case, `return *this;` returns the current object.

(Note that it is illegal to return automatic objects by reference, because they won't exist anymore when the caller tries to access them later.)

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes the reference is referred as a pointer to an object.  When you return `*this` as reference you actually return the exact object (without any copying) to the reference receiving it. The main difference between a reference and a pointer is that you can manipulate pointers (like changing the address they point to) but references cannot.

example :

```
int val = 4;
int *p = &val;
int &r = val;

p++ // Will pointer to the next memory located to val (addr(val) + sizeof(int)) 
(*p)++ // Will NOT increment val anymore as p pointer to another location
r++ // will increment value of val (you cannot increment the location r is pointing to). This is same as (*p)++.
```

both `p` and `r` are referring to the same location in memory (address of `val`) but the only difference is the way you access the value of val. (`*p` vs `r`)

Answer (score 1):

When you get acquianted with a difference between reference notion (`SomeType&`) and an address taking operator (`&SomeObject`), you may look into [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html), where there is a good explanation of what a reference is and how should you use it.