# Check if value really exists in a dynamic array? c++

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering if there was a way, in C++, to check if the value of a dynamic array actually exists.

```
int *x = new int[5];
```

Okay, so I think by default every value of x will be 0. But, the problem is that when I'm filling it with values, I may actually put in 0. Thus, this will cause confusion as to what tells us if the value really exists or not (0 seems to be the idiom that tells us it's NULL, but in this particular case I can't use that idiom because 0 may be a value that was given to me).

Is there another way to check if a value in a dynamic array is undefined?

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of a dynamic array"? In your code, the elements of the array are *uninitialized*, so they have *no* well-defined value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, first of all, as Jonathon said, there is no guarantee that the array will be initialized to `0`. You can either initialize it separately, or use `int *x = new int[5]();` which would do initialization for you.

As for how do you know which are valid. The simplest approach is to store a struct instead of `int`s. Something like this:

```
struct T {
    T() : valid(false), value(0) {
    }

    bool valid;
    int  value;
};

T *p = new T[5]; // each element will be initialized to false/0 because T has a constructor.
```

Then you can just do:

```
p[0].value = 10;
p[0].valid = true;
```

and so forth.

**EDIT:**
As a more advanced option, you can use operator overloading to make the `valid` flag get set automatically like this:

```
struct T {
    T() : valid(false), value(0) {
    }

    T &operator=(int x) {
        valid = true;
        value = x;
        return *this;
    }

    bool valid;
    int  value;
};

T *p = new T[5]; // each element will be initialized to false/0 because T has a 
p[1] = 10;       // p[1] is now true/10
```

Basically, assigning an integer value to the element, will automatically mark it as valid. Though in this particular example, I have not demonstrated how to "unset" a value back to being "invalid". This may or may not make sense for your use case or coding style, just some food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

If it is dynamically allocated, it will NOT be zeroed for you; you must initialize the array yourself by setting all entries to some default value. If zero is a valid entry, then consider using negative one.  If all positive and negative values are valid entries, then consider using a structure that contains the integer value, and a Boolean flag initialized to false.

In C, this would be:

```
typedef struct {
    bool valid;
    int  value;
} node;

node x[] = new node[5];
```

Comment: you are slightly off in your recommendation. This is a syntax error since your are using `typedef`, but not providing the alias it would be named. In addition, for this case, `typedef` isn't really needed at all, it's more of a c-ism.

Comment: Sorry, I am really much more of a C programmer than C++ these days. This is how I would do it in C, which was also tagged.

Comment: sure, though the c tag is a bit wrong, since this uses `new`. Of course if he used `malloc` the concept is of course the same, but he is clearly using c++.

Comment: still won't compile :-P. `node x[] = new node[5];` would probably be correct Java, but not c++...

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot sacrifice a value, say, the smallest negative or a largest positive `int`, to mean "not set", you need to keep track of what's set on the side. In C++ you can use `std::vector<bool>`:

```
int *x  = new int[5];
std::vector<bool> isSet(5, false);
if (!isSet[3]) {
    x[3] = 123;
    isSet[3] = true;
}
```

Comment: perfectly valid, but I would personally prefer to use an array of objects instead of 2 separate arrays because it eliminates the risk of the tracking array and the data array being out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

If they values you're going to use are going to be dense/contiguous, use `std::vector` (whose `size()` member will tell you how many items are currently valid). If the values are sparse, use `std::set` instead.

Either way, you'd be better off forgetting that `new T[size]` exists at all, not to mention subjecting yourself to the insanity of actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a dynamic array for this job, due to the many complexities that properly managing a resource involves. In my opinion, you should take a peek at `std::vector`, which would turn your code into something a bit like this:

```
#include <vector>

...

    std::vector<int> x();
    x.resize(5);
```

Now that would allow you to stop worrying about the bitch that resource management is, and focus into what is actually important (that is, handling your Xses).

Answer (score 0):

> But, the problem is that when I'm filling it with values, I may actually put in 0. Thus, this will cause confusion as to what tells us if the value really exists or not

There's no confusion as to whether a '0' really exists or not. If there's a 0 in the array that you didn't put there, it still exists. There's no difference between zeros that just happen to be in the array and zeros that you put there. If you need to distinquish between elements that you've assigned a value to versus elements that are not initialized, then you have to keep track of that information somewhere else.

```
bool *b = new bool[5](); // initialize the array to all false
int *x = new int[5]; // don't initialize the array
x[3] = 0; // set the fourth element in the array to 0
b[3] = true; // record that the fourth element in the array has been set
```

(Note, that [you shouldn't use raw arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264383/365496) and you shouldn't use new/delete)

---

> ```
> int *x = new int[5];
> ```
>
> Okay, so I think by default every value of x will be 0.

Not the way you're constructing that array; none of the `int`s in the array are initialized. They could have any value. Often when you build in 'debug' mode memory will be automatically zero initialized for you, but this is not specified by C++.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my other answer, another approach **if you think your valid indexes will be sparse**, would be to use `std::map` as an associative array like this:

```
std::map<int, int> x;
x[0] = 10;
x[2] = 123;
// indexes 0 and 2 are set, the rest do not exist.
```

To test if a value is preset, simply do:

```
if(x.find(n) != x.end()) {
    // there is a value at index n
} else {
    // no value found at index n
}
```

If your valid indexes are contiguous, you may as well just go with `std::vector`, or my original answer.