# Static 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, static

I am trying to define and use a 2-d array in C++

```
const float twitterCounts[][5] = {
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,2,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,0,0}
};
```

returning it like this:

```
const float ??? TwitterLiveData::data() {
    return twitterCounts;
}
```

and using it like this

```
float x = TwitterLiveData::data()[1][1];
```

What is the proper signature for the static accessor?

Comment: It's a lot easier to just use a vector. Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return an array, but you can return the pointer to its first element or reference to the array. You just have to put the correct type in the signature:

```
const float (*TwitterLiveData::data())[5] {
```

Or maybe

```
const float (&TwitterLiveData::data())[3][5] {
```

Answer (score 3):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264383/365496

summary:

```
#include <array>

const std::array<std::array<float,5>,3>
twitterCounts = {
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,2,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,0,0}
};

const std::array<std::array<float,5>,3>
TwitterLiveData::data() {
    return twitterCounts;
}
```

You may not want to return the array by value as that could potentially be too expensive. You could return a reference to the array instead:

```
const std::array<std::array<float,5>,3> &TwitterLiveData::data();
```

In either case your desired syntax `float x = TwitterLiveData::data()[1][1];` works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler, but most of the times a double array's name counts as a double pointer.
So in your case twitterCounts is a float**.

Comment: Not true. `twitterCounts` will never be a `float **` but as an array of type `float[5]` it will decay into a pointer to type `float[5]`; so `twitterCounts` "is a" (decays to) `float (*)[5]`