# The difference between int a[5] and int (&a)[5] in template parameter deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-argument-deduction

This question is about functions that take arrays of statically known size.

Take for example the following minimal program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
void arrfun_a(int a[N])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i]++ << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    arrfun_a<5>(a);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    arrfun_a<5>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Which, when run, prints the expected result:

```
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
```

However, when I tried to have my compiler (VS 2010) deduce the `5`, it `could not deduce template argument for 'int [n]' from 'int [5]'`.

A bit of research resulted in the updated `arrfun_b` where the template parameter deduction works:

```
template<size_t n>
void arrfun_b(int (&a)[n])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << ++(a[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

The result of the program is the same, whether `arrfun_a` or `arrfun_b` is called.

So far, the only difference I have found is whether the template argument deduction works and if it is possible to call the function with an N that is not 5...

Comment: Are you sure, that 'both versions allow explicitly passing an N that is smaller or larger'? It shouldn't and [doesn't](http://ideone.com/74FaV) for me. And it is another _pro_ to use reference version

Comment: Thank you for fixing my confusion! At some place during the testing, I must have screwed up with that!

Comment: You must didn't delete non-reference version and created an overload, that was called.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array (not really a dupe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler silently changes the type of function argument `int a[N]` to `int *a` and thus loses the size of the array. `int(&a)[5]` is truly a reference to an array of size 5, and cannot be passed an array of any other size.

Comment: More importantly, `int a[5]` becomes `int *a` in a parameter list where `int (&a)[5]` is truly a **reference** to an array of 5 `int`s

Comment: @D.Shawley, I implied that but didn't make it explicit. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, the call to `arrfun_a` would include an array-to-pointer decay followed by an implicit pointer-to-array-of-five conversion, leaving me with a totally useless compiler message? *great*

Comment: @dionadar: There is no conversion back to an array.  Inside arrfun_a, the type of `a` is a pointer.

Comment: OK, that finally got me what I was looking for: "[...] After
determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively. [...]" (8.3.5.5 in the C++ 11 standard)

Comment: Call me an old C fogey, but I don't see any "conversion" from int a[N]. int a[] IS int* a.  a[i] is just shorthand for *(a+i) where a is pointer to int and i is an int offet.

Comment: @Julian, you're confusing declarations with array indexing. Although they use the same syntax they are two different things.

Comment: @Julian `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)` because if `a` is an array then `a[i]` causes it to decay. _The array index operator does not operate on arrays._ But this doesn't mean that `int a[]` is nothing more than shorthand for `int *a`. The issue is simply that C arrays [behave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10264383/365496) [bizarrely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253277/365496).

Comment: @bames53 - in K&R C int a[] was definately just shorthand for pointer arithmetic - they borrowed it from BCPL. I'm sure you are right about how its defined now.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the difference between a reference and a pointer.

arrfun_a passes a pointer to int.

arrfun_b passes a reference to an array of ints.