# C++ 2D array function

Tags: c++, arrays, double

Basically I have,

```
    double marks [STUDENTS][ASSIGNMENTS] = {    (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7),
                                            (1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.5),
                                            (0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8),
                                            (0.8,0.9,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.8),
                                            (0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.5,0.9)};
```

And I want to get: `double studentAverages [STUDENTS]` from `studentAverages=calculateStudentAverages(marks);`

Using:

```
    double calculateStudentAverages (double marks[STUDENTS][ASSIGNMENTS]){
    double averages[STUDENTS];
    double average;
    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ASSIGNMENTS; j++) {
                average = average + marks[i][j];

            }
            averages[i]=average/ASSIGNMENTS;

    }    
    return averages;
}
```

But I get "cannot convert from 'double [5]' to 'double'" and "cannot convert from 'double' to 'double [5]'"

Comment: On which lines are you getting the errors?

Comment: You should avoid raw arrays as they [behave strangely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253277/365496)

Comment: The line where the function is called I get: 
'=' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'double [5]'
The return line in the functions gives:
'return' : cannot convert from 'double [5]' to 'double'

Comment: Welcome on SO. Did you know that you can edit your own question to modify or add more information? Please have a look to our FAQ as well http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your errors is from the fact that your function is declared to return a single `double` but you are attempting to return an array of `doubles`.  So you either need to change your function heading to accomodate for that, or only return one `double`

Not related to the errors, but you should definitely initialize `average` to `0.0` when you start, otherwise you have undefined behavior in the calculation

Comment: .. and `averages` can't really be returned from the function because they are local

Comment: I just need the averages of each row returned by the function as a vector but have no idea how.

Comment: @user1810269, bames53's link in your original question contains helpful information aso to how you should change your code to avoid errors and have well defined behavior

Comment: How can I just make averages a non-local array.

Comment: Do not do that.  Learn instead!