# Initialize pointer to array

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize pointer to struct array in my class constructor but it do not working at all...

```
class Particles {

private:

    struct Particle {
        double x, y, z, vx, vy, vz;
    };

    Particle * parts[];

public:

    Particles (int count)
    {
        parts = new Particle [count]; // < here is problem
    }

};
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: That's not a pointer to an array, that's an array of pointers to `Particle`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252837/pointer-to-array-c).

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of trouble by using an `std::vector<Particle>` instead of the dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove those `[]` from declaration. It should be

```
Particle *parts;
```

Using C++, you can use benefits of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
class Particles {
  // ...

 std::vector<Particle> parts;

 public:

    Particles (int count) : parts(count)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: @balki no, because `count` is not a compile time constant. But `std::vector<Particle>` would do fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Particle * parts[];
```

This is an array of pointers. To initialise this, you would need to loop through the array, initialising each of the pointers to point at a dynamically allocated `Particle` object.

You probably want to just make `parts` a pointer:

```
Particle* parts;
```

The `new[]` expression returns a pointer to the first element of the array - a `Particle*` - so the initialisation will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

class Particles {

private:

```
struct Particle {
    double x, y, z, vx, vy, vz;
};

Particle * parts;
```

public:

```
Particles (int count)
{
    parts = new Particle [count]; // < here is problem
}
```

};