# How to declare array with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have been playing with `auto` and I noticed that for most cases you can replace a variable definition with `auto` and then assign the type.

In the following code `w` and `x` are equivalent (default initialized `int`, but lets not get into potential copies).  Is there a way to declare `z` such that it has the same type as `y`?

```
int w{};
auto x = int{};
int y[5];
auto z = int[5];
```

Comment: The potential copies are important. You can't do this because you can't copy arrays.

Comment: Not "default initialized int", but "zero-initialized int"

Comment: Apparently, there is a problem creating a temporary array, and then copying it, as @DavidBrown intimated. Even using a `typedef` for an array type fails, because of this.

Comment: Implicit default constructor for an int does zero-initialize, unlike an unitialized int when has whatever garbage was already at the location.

Comment: @Graznarak: Except it isn't an "implicit default constructor".  Zero-filling of `int` (for example) occurs for value initialization and static initialization, but *not* default initialization.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
template<typename T, int N> using raw_array = T[N];

auto &&z = raw_array<int,5>{};
```

---

Your example of `auto z = int[5];` isn't legal any more than `auto z = int;` is, simply because a type is not a valid initializer. You can write: `auto z = int{};` because `int{}` is a valid initializer.

Once one realizes this, the next attempt would be:

```
auto z = int[5]{};
```

Note that your `int y[5]` does not have any initializer. If it had then you would have jumped straight here.

Unfortunately this does not work either for obscure syntax reasons. Instead you must find a legal way to name the array type in an initializer. For example, a typedef name can be used in an initializer. A handy reusable *template type alias* eliminates the burdensome requirement of a new typedef for every array type:

```
template<typename T, int N> using raw_array = T[N];

auto z = raw_array<int,5>{};
```

---

Aside: You can use template type aliases to fix the weird 'inside-out' syntax of C++, allowing you to name any compound type in an orderly, left-to-right fashion, by using [this proposal](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/left$20to$20right$20type$20syntax/std-proposals/xDQR3y5uTZ0/VKmOiLRzHqkJ).

---

Unfortunately due to the design bug in C and C++ which causes array-to-pointer conversions at the drop of a hat, the deduced type of the variable `z` is `int*` rather `int[5]`. The resulting variable becomes a dangling pointer when the temporary array is destroyed.

C++14 introduces `decltype(auto)` which uses different type deduction rules, correctly deducing an array type:

```
decltype(auto) z = raw_array<int,5>{};
```

But now we run into another design bug with arrays; they do not behave as proper objects. You can't assign, copy construct, do pass by value, etc., with arrays. The above code is like saying:

```
int g[5] = {};
int h[5] = g;
```

By all rights this should work, but unfortunately built-in arrays [behave bizarrely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253277/365496) in C and C++. In our case, the specific problem is that arrays are not allowed to have just any kind of initializer; they are strictly limited to using initializer lists. An array temporary, initialized by an initializer list, is not itself an initializer list.

---

#### Answer 1:

At this point Johannes Schaub makes the excellent suggestion that we can use temporary lifetime extension.

```
auto &&z = raw_array<int,5>{};
```

`decltype(auto)` isn't needed because the addition of `&&` changes the deduced type, so Johannes Schaub's suggestion works in C++11. This also avoids the limitation on array initializers because we're initializing a reference instead of an array.

If you want the array to deduce its length from an initializer, you can use an incomplete array type:

```
template<typename T> using unsized_raw_array = T[];

auto &&z = unsized_raw_array<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

---

Although the above does what you want you may prefer to avoid raw arrays entirely, due to the fact that raw arrays do not behave like proper C++ objects, and the obscurity of their behavior and the techniques used above.

#### Answer 2:

The `std::array` template in C++11 does act like a proper object, including assignment, being passable by value, etc., and just generally behaving sanely and consistently where built-in arrays do not.

```
auto z = std::array<int,5>{};
```

However, with this you miss out on being able to have the array type infer its own length from an initializer. Instead You can write a `make_array` template function that does the inference. Here's a really simple version I haven't tested and which doesn't do things you might want, such as verify that all the arguments are the same type, or let you explicitly specify the type.

```
template<typename... T>
std::array<typename std::common_type<T...>::type, sizeof...(T)>
make_array(T &&...t) {
    return {std::forward<T>(t)...};
}

auto z = make_array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: But I thought he wanted it to be uninitialized like `y`, or default initialized like `int{}`. Are you saying `int[5]{}` would work?

Comment: @jxh Yes, you can have a default initializer: `auto z = raw_array<int,100>{};`

Comment: @jxh that's a bug in gcc. However, I have discovered a problem that makes my answer incorrect. I'll have to update or delete my answer.

Comment: Specifically, although `raw_array<int,5>{}` does successfully produce an array temporary, the type deduced from it for the variable `z` is actually a pointer, pointing to the temporary. `z` then becomes a dangling pointer when the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: That is what GCC is warning about: `taking address of temporary array`.

Comment: That array initialization however is useless as you cannot use the pointer variable afterwarxs. Unlike C's compound literals, such a functional cast creates a temporary array object and will leave you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @jxh Ah, I see you're right. I remember at some poing gcc just didn't support this syntax.

Comment: What you *can* do is using lifetime extension with references, i.e `auto&&`.

Comment: In `make_array`, shouldn't it be `T&&...` (`&& before the ellipsis)? And I think there's a `T, ` too much in the return type. But very exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 10):

Not quite the same, but you could use `array`:

```
auto z = std::array<int, 5>();
```

Comment: For giggles, we made a [make_array function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6114067/596781) some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Better think about make_something from c++14

```
#include<iostream>
#include<experimental/array>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::experimental;
int main()
{
    auto arr = make_array(1,2,3);
    cout << arr.front() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`decltype` works with g++ 4.9.0 20130601 for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

static std::ostream& logger = std::clog;

class A {
    static int _counter;
    int _id;
  public:
    A() : _id(++_counter) {
        logger << "\tA #" << _id << " c'tored\n";
    } 

    ~A() {
        //logger << "\tA #" << _id << " d'tor\n";
    } 

    inline int id() const{
        return _id;
    }
};
int A::_counter(0); 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
    return os << a.id();
}

int main() {

    auto dump = [](const A& a){ logger << a << " ";};

    logger << "x init\n";
    A x[5]; 
    logger << "x contains: "; std::for_each(x, x+5, dump);

    logger << "\ndecltype(x) y init\n";
    decltype(x) y;
    logger << "y contains: ";  std::for_each(y, y+5, dump);
    logger << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x init
    A #1 c'tored
    A #2 c'tored
    A #3 c'tored
    A #4 c'tored
    A #5 c'tored
x contains: 1 2 3 4 5 
decltype(x) y init
    A #6 c'tored
    A #7 c'tored
    A #8 c'tored
    A #9 c'tored
    A #10 c'tored
y contains: 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same thing, and it's a bit ugly, but it is possible to deduce the element type from a list initializer and declare the array directly, as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct array_trait
{
    using element_type = T;
    array_trait(T(&&)[]);
};

decltype(array_trait({4,5,7}))::element_type a[] = {4,5,7};

std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
```

The type should be `int[3]` and the output should be `4 5 7`.