# Auto Rvalue Reference (without &&) to an Array in C++14

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, rvalue-reference, auto

Answer 1 of the post
[How to declare array with auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949016/how-to-declare-array-with-auto) works fine:

```
template<typename T> using unsized_raw_array = T[];
auto &&z = unsized_raw_array<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

Trying out the same but without the double ampersand (`&&`) results in different behavior of clang and gcc:

```
template<typename T> using unsized_raw_array = T[];
auto   z = unsized_raw_array<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

I expected this to be an error because it is an rvalue (universal/forwarding/temporary-object) reference and the double ampersand is missing (`&&`). And that is what happens with gcc 6.3.0:

- `error: taking address of temporary array`

However, clang 3.9.1 compiles and executes it successfully, allowing printing the values of the array in the next statements. I only get this warning (in some scenarios I don't even get the warning):

- `warning: pointer is initialized by a temporary array, which will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Waddress-of-array-temporary]`

Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang is correct; see [conv.array]:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N` `T`” or “array of unknown bound of `T`” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to `T`”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Even if the array is a temporary, and therefore a prvalue, it is legal to perform the array-to-pointer conversion on it.

It appears that the restriction on converting array prvalues into pointers was introduced in a patch that resolved [gcc bug 53220](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53220). It seems that a consensus emerged on the thread that allowing the conversion was dangerous since initializing a pointer variable from the array would not extend the lifetime of the array. However, treating such code as though it is ill-formed is not the correct solution, since, as pointed out later in the thread, it is possible to use this conversion in a safe way, *e.g.,* if the array is being passed to a function that takes a pointer (and therefore will live until the function returns).

You would probably have to file a new bug against gcc in order to get them to fix the issue.

Comment: In that case, why does clang output a warning saying that the array `will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression`? If I get it right, that means that after that statement the array would be destroyed and, thus, not accesible. However, I can access and print the contents of the array after that, so it seems it is not destroyed as clang suggests. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @JL It's true, the array is destroyed. Attempting to access it after the end of the statement results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both compilers might be right! Although I'm not sure about the specific case (anybody willing to look up?), there are many situations the C++ standard just requires to give any diagnostic at all, but does not mandate a specific one of them, so both error or warning only can comply with the standard.

Additionally, have a look at your compiler flags - most (including [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)) compilers allow to turn warnings into errors via flags...

Comment: I know what you mean, I faced a similar situation to what you describe several weeks ago. However, I'm not sure if this is one of this cases where both may be right... Regarding the compiler flags, I am just interested in knowing what is the correct approach, not to get my code compile. Thanks.