# Address of array prvalue

Tags: c++, arrays, temporary-objects

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
auto a = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

> error: taking address of temporary array
```

I understand that array lvalues decay to pointers when converted to rvalues but here the array is already an rvalue (actually a prvalue) so no decay should be needed. I would have expected `a` to be deduced and initialized to `int[5]`. Why is it trying to take the address of a temporary?

Comment: I'm watching for an answer, but. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949016/how-to-declare-array-with-auto) may be relevant as auto can't do that.

Comment: This grammar is [ill-formed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/iFGbmN).

Answer (score 5):

> I would have expected `a` to be deduced and initialized to `int[5]`

Sadly, this is not how C arrays work. Arrays decays into pointers. You cannot really have an "array value". If you replace auto by the deduced type, it looks like this:

```
int* a = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The decay must take the address to make the pointer.

This is easily fixed by using references, since reference to temporaries extends their lifetime:

```
auto&& a = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // works!
```

Here's the example running on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rjrgo4).

Of course, with `std::array` you get a nice syntax and value semantics:

```
auto a = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: `auto a = (const int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` should also work.

Comment: Hi @Unimportant , I get the same compiler error with vs141, even with the constant.

Comment: @lakeweb Perhaps vs141 does not allow compound literals, which are strictly speaking not supported by C++. gcc allows them (but will warn when compiled with `-pedantic`). That's a separate issue from the storage issue in the question.

Comment: I don't get your agumentation chain. `std::is_same_v<decltype((int[5]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), int[5]>` returns true and `std::is_same_v<decltype((int*){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), int[5]>` returns false, so why `auto a = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` should be the same as `int* a = (int[])(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`? I can't find the line in the draft which found your theses. Since `int[5]` is an aggregate type at least `auto a = (int[5]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` should work... I mean `auto aggregate = (A){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` is also wroking for each aggregate type A with 5 int members.

Comment: Hi @Unimportant , yes, this is not the first time I've run into gcc allowing something not c++ and where Microsoft just stays strict about it. Thanks.

Comment: "Arrays decays into pointers". Decay "happens when an lvalue expression is used as an rvalue" (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay/). But here the array is already an rvalue, so there should be no decay...

Comment: @SirVisto I wouldn't treat cpluslus.com as ground truth. The standard is always more precise. You could ask a question with the `language-lawyer` tag, but this one is quite easy. Decays always happen, whether you have r-value or l-value. Here's [an expample](https://godbolt.org/z/2GYvXM).

Comment: @Guillaume: That's not quite the same: (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5} is a true rvalue (prvalue), whereas int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; std::move(arr) gives an rvalue reference (xvalue), which needs to be de-referenced, which is when decay could occur. For the former case, it seems odd to have a prvalue magically convert to another prvalue - but then, C++ array behaviour is odd anyway.

Comment: @SirVisto The thing is, decay is not influenced by R- or L- values. The text un cplusplus.com is misleading. I suggest not using that particular paragraph as reference.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Your example has nothing to do with array-to-pointer conversion, auto placeholder deduction does the same as template argument deduction. Since `std::move(arr)` has type `int (&&)[5]`, the type referred to, i.e., `int [5]`, is used for type deduction. That's what auto is deduced.In the function case, another function parameter type adjustment is performed