# No array bounds check when using auto

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

When having [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/1rUJ0m) compiling with `-Warray-bounds`. I get a warning when declaring array2 `array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 3 elements)`. But not when declaring array1 even though it has to be the same type thus carrying the same size information. Is this a bug in clang?

```
enum class Format : int {
  Off = 55,
  FormatA = 66,
  FormatB = 77,
};

inline Format (&AllFormats())[3] {
  static Format values[] = {
    Format::Off,
    Format::FormatA,
    Format::FormatB
  };
  return values;
}

int main()
{
    auto array1 = AllFormats();    
    auto v3 = array1[3];

    Format (&array2)[3] = AllFormats();    
    v3 = array2[3];
}
```

Comment: How have you verified they have the same type? You might want to recheck that.

Comment: Instead of C-style arrays, use `std::array<Format, 3>`. You'll find that the code is much easier to write and much easier to understand.

Comment: @pete You are right. In my code I would use std::array. The code shown was roughly generated by the google flatbuffers compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> even though it has to be the same type

You’d think that. But if you check, you’ll find that they actually don’t have the same type:

```
std::cout << typeid(array1).name() << "\n";
std::cout << typeid(array2).name() << "\n";
```

```
P6Format
A3_6Format
```

Oops. The array returned by `AllFormats` decays to a pointer when assigned to an `auto` variable because that’s how the type deduction rules for `auto` work. Compare:

```
int& foo() {
    static int x = 42;
    return x;
}

auto x = foo(); // Type of `x` is `int`, not `int&`.
```

To prevent this, declare `array1` as `auto&` or `auto&&`.

Comment: It's stuff like this that really makes me lose faith in C++!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The deduction rules are unintuitive but at least they’re consistent. A lot of these issues are avoided by simply never using C arrays. Personally I violate that rule but I should probably just swallow the bitter pill and use `std::array` everywhere. None of that should detract from your valid criticism though.

Comment: Indeed. I've started preferring `std::array` but can't promise I always bother ;)

Answer (score 4):

`array1` is a pointer.

Use`auto&&` instead of `auto` there.

Comment: Great this fixed it. But I need to learn more about what ``auto&&`` actually means. Thanks

Comment: `decltype(auto)` can also work as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949016/how-to-declare-array-with-auto

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko Sure, but that is more verbose, and only makes a difference that doesn't really matter (an rvalue reference to an extended lifetime temporary, vs a value) in practice (like, 9999/10000 times).

Answer (score 4):

> But not at line 16 even though it has to be the same type

Assuming by **it** you refer to `auto array1 = AllFormats()`, then it doesn't have the same type. `auto` is never deduced to be a reference, so `array1` is not a reference. It is a non-reference, and is deduced to be the decayed result, i.e. a pointer to `Format`.

As the pointer type doesn't carry information about the size of the pointed array, the compiler wasn't able to prove that the subscript operator overflows the array.

To declare a reference, you can use either:

```
auto&          array1 = AllFormats(); // 1.
auto&&         array1 = AllFormats(); // 2.
decltype(auto) array1 = AllFormats(); // 3.
```

1. Declares explicitly an lvalue reference.
2. Declares a universal reference, which collapses into an lvalue reference, because `AllFormats` returns an lvalue reference. It would be an rvalue reference if `AllFormats` returned `Format&&`.
3. `auto` type deduction uses different rules from `decltype` deduction. One key difference is that `auto` is never a reference, while `decltype(E);` may be a reference, depending on the expression `E`. `decltype(auto) var = E` allows a declaration using the `decltype` rules as if `decltype(E)` was used.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
auto array1 = AllFormats();    
auto v3 = array1[3];
```

`array1` is not an array, so no bounds can be checked.  Even though you return by reference, `auto` is not going to deduce one so instead the array decays into a pointer and `array1` gets deduces as a `Format *`.

```
Format (&array2)[3] = AllFormats();    
v3 = array2[3];
```

Generates a warning because `array2` is a reference to an array so it knows the size.

---

To get `auto` to deduce an array you either need to use `auto&`, which will only work if what is returned is an lvalue reference, or `auto&&` which will bind a reference to anything.