# Finding a book from a list of books using string array

Tags: c++, pointers

The question is check whether a particular book is found or not in a list of books.
I know how to do directly but need to use pointer.
Please help me to debug the second code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,c=0;
    char A[10][100],s[10];
    cout<<"Enter no:of books: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>A[i];
    cout<<"Enter book you want to search: ";
    cin>>s;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(A[i],s)==0)
        c++;
    }
    if(c==0)
    cout<<"Not found";
    else
    cout<<"Book found";
}
```

I want to do this using pointer. Kindly help me

I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,c=0;
    char A[10][100],s[10];
    const char *p[10][100];
    cout<<"Enter no:of books: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>A[i];
    cout<<"Enter book you want to search: ";
    cin>>s;
    p=&A[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(*p,s)==0)
        c++;
        p++;
    }
    if(c==0)
    cout<<"Not found";
    else
    cout<<"Book found";
}
```

But not working

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `const char *p[10][100];` to `char (*p)[100];` will solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i,c=0;
    char A[10][100],s[10];
    char (*p)[100];

    cout<<"Enter no. of books: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {cout << "Enter book name : "; cin>>A[i];}

    cout<<"Enter book you want to search: ";
    cin>>s;
    p = &A[0];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(*p,s)==0)
            c++;
        p++;
    }
    if(c==0)
        cout<<"Not found";
    else
        cout<<"Book found";
}
```

Result :

```
Enter no. of books: 3
Enter book name : abc
Enter book name : def
Enter book name : ghi
Enter book you want to search: abc
Book found
```

Why is so?

- Firstly, `char *p[10][100]` will declare an array **of array of pointers**, while `char *p[100]` only declare an array of pointers.
- Secondly, `char *p[100]` declare an **array of pointers**, while `char (p*) [100]` declare **a pointer to a `char[]` array**. Notice the `array of pointers` to `pointer to array`.

Also, see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Related : [pointer to array c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252837/pointer-to-array-c/10252927)