# Why does c++ pointer * associate to the variable declared, not the type?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-design, declaration

Why was C++ designed such that the correct way to declare two int *s on the same line is

```
int *x, *y;
```

not

```
int* x,y;
```

I know some people think you should avoid either form and declare every variable on its own line, but I'm interested in why this language decision was made.

Comment: Because that's the way it's done in C.

Comment: may be they thought to be more flexible that a user can declare both a pointer and a normal variable at the same time.

Comment: Read this http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace for the reason in C++, for C reasons: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html

Comment: I would say the strangest part is with initialization. Let's say we have `int* p = new int[5];` Then `int* a = &p;` would be fine: "Give to the pointer a the address of p". But `int *b = &p;` is strange: "Give to the integer *b the address of p". Considering *b is an int, why giving addresses? That's why I find the chained declarations of pointer make no sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the distinctions between the various symbols (*,&, etc) combined with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636903/what-are-the-distinctions-between-the-various-symbols-etc-combined-with-p)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To keep compatibility with C code, because that's how C works.

Bjarne makes a good point [in his style and technique faq](//www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace):

> The choice between `int* p;` and `int *p;` is not about right and wrong, but about style and emphasis. C emphasized expressions; declarations were often considered little more than a necessary evil. C++, on the other hand, has a heavy emphasis on types.
>
> A typical C programmer writes `int *p;` and explains it `*p is what is the int` emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++) declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed, the * binds to the name p in the grammar.
>
> A `typical C++ programmer` writes `int* p;` and explains it `p is a pointer to an int` emphasizing type. Indeed the type of p is int*. I clearly prefer that emphasis and see it as important for using the more advanced parts of C++ well.

So, the motivation for this working as this in C++ is how it works in C.

The motivation it works like that in C is that, as stated above, C emphasizes expressions rather than types.

Comment: @illEatYourPuppies ah but that's an entirely different question :P

Comment: The short answer is above: "C emphasized expressions; declarations were often considered little more than a necessary evil."

Comment: @LuchianGrigore only if you have no curiosity whatsoever :)

Comment: I usually run with `int * p` because I find both ways ugly :)

Comment: @nijansen that's the ugliest of all, I read that as "calculate the product of `int` and `p` (by multiplication)"!

Comment: You would have to observe that Bjarne's last paragraph is wrong. I've never seen a C++ programmer do that, and it is inoonsistent with the actual meaning. Consider the OP's example: int* p,q; does not mean that q is a pointer to int.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is: because that's the way C does it.  Which, of
course, only begs the question: why does C do it this way?

The original philosophy, in early C, is that the declaration be an exact
image of the use.  So when you write:

```
int *p;
```

, you are declaring that the expression `*p` has type `int` (and the
compiler works out the actual type of `p` accordingly).

This, of course, ceased to be true the day C introduced `typedef`, and
later `struct`.  And any resemblance disappeared completely with `const`
(first introduced in C++, then retrofitted into C), where things like

```
int *const p;
```

have no relationship with use.  But by then, the die was cast.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

That comes from "C" ( "plain c", "pure c", whatever ).

When a pointer variable is already declared, its used like this:

```
...
*p = &x;
*q = SomePointerFunc();
....
```

I read that the original inventors of "c" wanted programmers to declare pointers variables with the same syntax as they are used, **with the star before the variable identifier**:

```
...
int *p;
int *q;
...
```

The same goes for arrays:

```
...
x[5]  = 'a';
y[77] = SomeItemFunc();
...

...
char x[5];
int  y[100];
...
```

Some teachers that I had, insist to declare types for variables & functions this way (star close to identifier):

```
...
int *p;
int *q;
...
```

Instead of this (star next to type identifier):

```
...
int* p;
int* q;
...
```

**Extra**

In Java, and other languages, like C#, the declaration of arrays, or pointers are next to the type, leaving the variable or function identifier alone, like this pseudocode:

```
*int p;
*int q;
char[5] x;
int[100]  y;
```

I prefer this technique.

Cheers.