# what's the meaning of *&

Tags: c++

I am a java coder and not familar with the c++ language.
But right now,i read the following code:

```
void method(A* a,A*& b);

A *a;
A *b;
method(a,b);
```

And my question is:
what's the meaning of "*&"?Does it means that it represent the value of b itself?
thx

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637342/365496) to understand what the two different meanings of `&` are. Your question "Does it means that it represent the value of b itself?" makes it sound like you are confusing them and thinking that `*&b` here means "take the address of b and then dereference it." The linked answer makes it clear why it doesn't mean that in this context.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a reference to a pointer of `A`.

So if `method` sets `b`, the `b` in scope of the call will be changed.

Comment: @dirkgently: question's tagged 'c++'

Answer (score 0):

Read it from right to left. `A*& b` says that `b` is a reference to an object that points to an `A`. Why is this useful? It allows you to directly modify the pointer that is being passed into the function. Whatever happens to `b` inside that function will be visible when the function returns.

Comment: Well,but,if i pass the pointer into the function,like a,in my example,the function's modification of a still takes effect.Right?

Comment: It really depends on what is happening inside `method`. Anyways, this is getting beyond the scope of the question because it sounds like you do yet not have a firm grasp on how pointers and references work. The only way to truly understand them is to experiment yourself with test programs, etc.