# C++ ClassName::GetSth(TypeName* &pSth)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what’s the meaning of *&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060112/whats-the-meaning-of)

1. what `* &pSth` mean?
2. is this a `pointer` or a `ref`?
3. Why/When we need that?

--code--

```
ClassName::GetSth(TypeName* &pSth)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: @jogojapan actually i'm not just asking what is that, the important is when/how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "reference to pointer to Typename".

Answer (score 1):

`TypeName* &pSth` is a reference to `TypeName` pointer.

Equivalent syntax in C is `TypeName** pSth`